# Route and distance measuring in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-plugins, software-recommendations

I'm looking for a plugin that can make a route from given GPS points and then calculate the distance of this route.
I'm going to create GPS points and import it to Qgis as a GPX file.
I know I can calculate distances/polylines alone but I wanted to know if there was a plugin that did both.

Comment: Is the route supposed to be just a connection of the input points or do you want to compute the route on an underlying network?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but there is a plugin
for Qgis called qProf that allows you, amongst other things, to upload 
GPX files and plot them.